# Change the color in between cells in grouped table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, grouped-table

I need to know how to change the color in between the cells in Grouped UITableView

Note: the UITableView have a Background color of some other color

So, How to implement the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I do believe the correct way to do this is setBackgroundColor for the tableview. you can do this in the viewDidLoad method so the color is already set when the view loads*

**Edit:**

I would suggest make a custom subclass of UITableViewCell with the background color/image already included in the cell. Then you would have to also set the headers and footers to have the same background color/image. I believe this would be the easiest way to accomplish what you want

Comment: I do want the background color of the UITableView to be of some other color

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking for then. If you want a different color just in between the cells I would suggest implementing  viewForHeaderInSection. You can set the frame and background color of your new view to whatever you like. I hope that helps!

Comment: I need to implement attached screen!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking... Could you explain it a little better?

Comment: 1.I've a `UITableView` which is of style: `UITableViewStyleGrouped`  2.I need to give a background color of `blue` so when I drag the table I could see the blue color    3.The space in between the cells should take a background image.   (exactly as the image shows)

Comment: That is very hard to do. honestly what I would do is create a subclass of UITableViewCell and set the background color (or image) on your custom cell then use the custom cell in your tableview. I believe this would also require custom headers and footers, but i think it would be the easiest way to accomplish what you are asking. does that help at all?

Comment: Yes.. Could you please edit your answer so I could accept it?